# Spring MVC @Cacheable annotation on Generic Method

Tags: spring, hibernate, caching, spring-mvc, annotations

### I am using spring MVC with Hibernate

**Generic Method**

```
    // getAllById
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> List<T> getAllById(Class<T> entityClass, long id)
        throws DataAccessException {
Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(entityClass)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));

    return criteria.list();
}
```

**In controller**

```
List<GenCurrencyModel> currencyList=pt.getAllById(GenCurrencyModel.class,1);
```

**Question**

How we can use **@Cacheable("abc") annotation** in Generic method and destroy the cache on demand using spring mvc + hibernate with generic DAO

**According to the example in [spring doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html)** it specify annotation on simple method !

```
@Cacheable("books")
public Book findBook(ISBN isbn) {...}
```

**I actually required, when Id pass to generic method ,it should first look up in cache, and I should also destroy cache on demand !**

Comment: I can't see any problem. Does your own code not work as expected or do you need an explanation of something?

Comment: @zeroflagL if I specify @Cacheable("books") in generic method , then next time, this generic method is used for "library" or "Student" instead of "book" ! this is my problem !

Answer (score 6):

First of all think about the implications of using Generics for a moment:

- You don't know which types you will use in the future. You don't know the cache names either for that matter.
- You (may) have no type information, so there is no chance of choosing a specific cache.

The last point can be solved by **always** providing type information, like `entityClass` in your method.

### Solution 1: One cache

Use one cache and generate a key based on the type.
`@Cacheable(value="myCache", key="#entityClass.name + #id")`

### Solution 2: Use @Caching

While you can use expressions for the key you can't use them for the cache names. `@Caching` allows you to use multiple `@Cachable` annotations, each with another cache name.

```
@Caching (
@Cacheable(value="books", key="#id", condition="#entityClass.name == 'Book'"),
@Cacheable(value="students", key="#id", condition="#entityClass.name == 'Student')
)
```

### Solution 3: Write your own cache provider

This is not much of an effort to do. The Spring default cache provider is just a map after all. Your implementation could use different 'subcaches' for each type.

Clearing the cache is more difficult. The solutions 1 and 3 have only one cache. You cannot clear only 'books' but not 'students'. Solution 2 has that option but you have to provide all possible caches and types.
You could use solution 3 and talk to the cache directly instead of using `@CacheEvict`.