# Spring cache applying caching on a generic method by dynamically getting the cachname based on the return type

Tags: java, caching, spring-cache

The method `getById` is located in an Abstract class named `AbstractCachedResult`.

```
public abstract class AbstractCachedResult<T extends BaseResource> {

    @Cacheable(value = "dynamicName")
    public T getById(String id){
      //program logic
    }
}
```

Many other service classes will be inheriting from this class. For ex :

```
public class UserService extends AbstractCachedResult<User> {
    
    //program logic
}
```

Since I am setting the `@Cacheable(value = "dynamicName")` in the abstract class I wouldn't be able to know the type of the class that was returned by the method. I need to be able to get the name of the class dynamically so that for each method invocation from its inherited class the correct cache is used.

I have came across another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17377270/spring-mvc-cacheable-annotation-on-generic-method). Here they are passing the entity class name as a parameter which I cannot do. I need to get the type of the returned data dynamically so that I could us the @Caching annotation which is the #2 soluton. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Arguably, the simplest and most obvious solution, especially for maintainers, would be to override the `getById(:String)` method in the subclass, like so:

```java
public class UserService extends AbstractCachedResult<User> {

    @Cacheable("UserCache")
    public User getById(String id) {
        super.id(id);
    }

    // additional logic
}
```

Alternatively, you might be able to implement a "custom" `CacheResolver` (see [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-cache-resolver) and [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/CacheResolver.html)) that is able to inspect the class generic signature of the (target) subclass.

Finally, under-the-hood, *Spring's Cache Abstraction* is implemented with *Spring* AOP. For real, low-level control, it should be possible to write custom AOP Interceptor not unlike *Spring's* default `CacheInterceptor` ([Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/CacheInterceptor.html)). Your own AOP Advice could even be ordered relative to the Cacheable Advice, if needed.

Honestly, I think the first option I presented above is the best approach. Not every service class may need to cache the result of the `getById(:String)` operation. Caching really depends on the transactional nature of the data and how frequently the data changes.

Use your best judgement.